# Use of ternary operator without using assignment or return

Tags: c#

Hi I have a problem like

```
bool isCompleted = true;

if(isCompleted){x= 5}
```

so i want use above code using ternary operator without using return or assignment like

```
isCompleted ? int x = 5 : <do nothing>;
```

So is it possible to use ternary operator without using return or assignment?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be storing or using the result of ternary operator in some expression otherwise I see not point of using ternary operator.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does the ternary operator accomplish here? Why, if you insist on it for liking question marks, not just do: `x = isCompleted ? 5 : 0;`

Comment: this code is sample code and as my requirement i don't want to use assignment (x) as i just want like: true?<do new logic>:<nothing>

Answer (score 3):

Try using it like this :

```
x = isCompleted  ? intValue(if true) : intValue(if false);
```

Since you have declared `x` as `int`, you will have to provide the values in `int` irrespective of the condition evaluated. Any other type value you use wont work here. Hence the `false` that you wrote is wrong. You might want to provide an `int` value there.

Incase if you want to perform some code logic based on bool conditions, you might want to use `if...else` here as that will help you do more than just assigning some values to variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: HarveySpecter this code is sample code
and as my requirement i don't want to use assignment (x) as  
i just want like:
true?<do new logic>:<nothing>

Comment: if you want to perform some logic instead of just assigning some value to variables, you might want to use `if`. That way you can execute whatever logic you want when `if` condition is true and do nothing when its false. In short,using simple `if...else`.

Comment: yes this was the ultimate solution but i thought about ternary so that i can optimize my code, anyways thanks.

Comment: Of course it does optimize. Even I prefer it, but in some cases like these, you dont have much of a choice. Glad that it helped you and I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need the assignment prior to the boolean.

```
x = isCompleted ? 5: 0;
```

Secondly, you have a type error. The above will set x=5 if isCompleted = true otherwise it will set x=0

```
isComplete ? 5 :false
```

Will fail to compile as you can't assign a boolean to an int.

Comment: Jon

As i don't want to use this assignment operator

Comment: Understandable. If that is the case as the below have pointed out, you'd be stronger with an if statement. Tertiary operators are good, but sometime not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Read about ternary operator's syntax ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)):

> The conditional operator (?:) **returns** one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

So your code must be rewriten as:

```
x = isCompleted ? 5 : 0;
```

Comment: Yoh Deadfall this code is sample code and as my requirement i don't want to use assignment (x) as i just want like: true?<do new logic>:<nothing>

Comment: Use `if` operator: `if (isCompleted) x = 5;`

Comment: yes this was the ultimate solution but i thought about ternary so that i can optimize my code, anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to set x to 5 if true. Otherwise keep x value?

> x = isCompleted ? 5: x: