# Single line If condition without else clause

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, assignment-operator, conditional-operator

How can we write a single line If condition without else in the operator?

Example:

> If(count==0) { count=2; }

How can we write above like below:

> count=count==0?2;

As ternary operator requires if else condition. I want to do it without the ternery operator. Is there any operator available in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  Just use an `if` statement.

Comment: The `if (count==0) { count=2; }` you started with is "a single line `if` statement without `else`".  What's wrong with that, or the ternary operator for that matter?  Those are the ways C# provides to do this, so that's what you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [? operator without else-part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934860/operator-without-else-part) or [Use of ternary operator without using assignment or return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29695333/150605) or [Is it possible to put only one option on a ternary expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36079961/150605)

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to pair `else` with `if`; you can use it on its own:

```
if (count == 0)
        count = 2;
```

This can be written in multiple ways if the syntax isn't to your liking:

```
if (count == 0) count = 2;

if (count == 0) { count = 2; }

if (count == 0) {
    count = 2;
}

if (count == 0)
{
    count = 2;
}
```

---

As another poster points out, you can use nullable int with initialization to `null` to have a binary interaction with the null coalescing operator:

```
int? count = null; // initialization

// ... later

count = count ?? 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
count = count == 0 ? 2 : count;
```

Or for more fun:

```
using System;               
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach(int x in System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(-5, 10))
        {
            int count = x;
            bool y = count == 0 && (0 == count++ - count++);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use ternary operator? What's the absolute need fo this?